# Display column names and add check boxes php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, information-schema

I have a task to list the column names with the data type tiny int. I used SHOW COLUMNS but I would like to use the results to make a field in my form based on the show columns result.

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work? What *exactly* are you trying to do and what step are you getting hung up on?

Comment: I have ran a sql query and all i want is to get column names of a table with data-type tinyint. Similar to this question:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?51,158277,158277#msg-158277

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbName' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tableName' AND 
        LOWER(DATA_TYPE) = 'tinyint'
```